# xubuntu 12.04 vlc 2.0.3 dual monitor refresh different rates problem

Tags: 12.04, dualhead, framerate

I have a xubuntu 12.04 setup with NVIDIA GT610 proprietary driver, TV with HDMI and vga monitor.
it worked perfect with 11.10 and vlc 1.1.X with 60Hz on VGA and 50 Hz on TV.

Now with 12.04 and 2.0.3 vlc i can't have different refresh rates, video get totally messed up, tearing, jerky, out of lipsync. Using 60 Hz on both monitors works with the inherent problems of 50 Hz video on 60 Hz monitor, regular jerking. Same at least wit ATI adapter.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own experience with 12.04, performance seems to degrade on multi-display desktop, regardless of your refresh rates or any other display settings for that matter.  Though using single or single display desktop (multi-display desktop, one workspace for each display) will maintain normal FPS during video playback or rendering.

Because you mentioned both ATI and Nvidia having this issue, I'm going to assume it might be something specific with Xubuntu and running any dual display desktop.  I'm curious if other variants of Ubuntu has this issue also.